# Avoiding indexing HTML tags as search keywords

Tags: java, html, lucene

I'm indexing keywords in an HTML document, but I don't want to index the HTML tags.

For example:

```html
<div>  <!-- this is html code -->
<span>You are welcome</span>  <!-- simple message for searching -->
<div>
<h1>Testing text</h1>  <!-- second message -->
</div>
</div>
```

Expected keywords:

```
keywords:You
```

How can I avoid the HTML tags becoming keywords?

Comment: `HTMLStripCharFilter` maybe?

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to parse the HTML and extract the inner text of each tag.

Comment: Any parser is available for parse jsp page??